# Checking duplicate in big table

Tags: mysql

I have a big table. I am finding duplicates, this table has 10 columns(lets say A,B,C,D..etc). I am running below query to get duplicate record but its taking  more than 1 hour.
Query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY A,B,C,D,E HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Can someone suggest me faster way to get this done.

Comment: You need all column which is having different values?

Comment: how many rows in the table exactly? And what hardware? Lots of things can impact on performance, not just the query. Anyway, if this is a one-off operation, does it matter if it takes a little while? However i#f you're doing this regularly to remove duplicates, ask yourself why - shouldn't you be changing the primary key on the table so the duplicates can't be created in the first place?

Comment: If you just trying to remove the duplicate rows after finding them, Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Comment: My requirement is get if column A,B,C,D,E can make a unique index on this table or not. This table has already a number of records. So, I am finding duplicates in existing records.

Comment: yes you've already said that, but that doesn't answer my question about whether this is a one-off job or something you want to repeat regularly. If it's just to be run once then maybe speed doesn't matter so much?

Answer (score 0):

Check Performance by applying this query!

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_name mt
JOIN
(SELECT A,B,C,D,E FROM tbl_name GROUP BY A,B,C,D,E HAVING COUNT(*) >1) T 
ON mt.A= T.A
and mt.B= T.B
and mt.C= T.C
and mt.D= T.D
and mt.E= T.E
```